# How to override existing column in Django admin list display?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-1.10

I'm trying to figure out how to override column values in Django admin list display.

My model has field `response_bytes` which is in `list_display` in `MyModelAdmin`. 
I want admin to show this value in MB or KB etc.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [f.name for f in MyModel._meta.fields] # This contains response_bytes

    def response_bytes(self,obj):
        return filesize.size(obj.response_bytes)

    def request_bytes(self,obj):
        return filesize.size(obj.request_bytes)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't call methods below. If I created new `list_display` items with custom names and then rename these methods, it would work.

Can I override existing fields or do I have to define new columns?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it this similar way instead of overriding the column

```
class MyModeL(models.Model):
    filesize = model.ACertainFieldIAmUsing( ...

    @property
    def change_bytes(self):
        if float(self.filesize) / 1048576 > 1:
            return "%s MB" % (float(self.filesize) / 1048576)
        elif float(self.filesize) / 1024 > 1:
            return "%s KB" % (float(self.filesize) / 1024)
        else:
            return "%s B" % (self.filesize)
```

Then in your model admin.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('change_bytes', ...)
```

Code is untested but something close to this should work